# Unreal MouseWheelAxis negative axis does not work

Tags: c++, input, unreal-4, axis

Would like to avoid using separate action mappings i.e. `MouseWheelUp` and `MouseWheelDown` for a system I'm developing.

I noticed `MouseWheelAxis` and put that as my axis event. This only works on the forward movement of the mouse wheel, and not on the backwards, as stated. (presumably because the scale is set to +1.0)

Why?

And how can I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to assign the mouse wheel scrolling action to a regular axis mapping as you would do with two different keys.

The only option available is using MouseWheelUp to scale +1.0 (or what you need) and MouseWheelDown to scale -1.0.

This is by design and is not considered a bug.

---

Edit based on my own tests and from new comments.

I'm not sure why you're only seeing result when the wheel moves forward.

I went into the input settings and added a new axis event based on mouse wheel axis:
[image: UE4 Unreal 4 Add new Input Binding]

Then went into the level blueprint and set up a simple chain for getting to a print string:
[image: UE4 Unreal 4 MouseWheelAxis Blueprint BP]

And finally, ran the program, scrolling the mouse wheel back and forth:
[image: UE4 Unreal 4 MouseWheelAxis screen result]

As you can see, I'm getting 1.0 and -1.0 results so can't say why you're not seeing the same.

Please note that I'm using engine version 4.22 for this.  Based on previous research, I didn't think this was possible so it may be a new feature added on a later version of the engine.

Comment: Ah I'm so sorry, the first sentence should read 'separate action mappings'.   As the two specified do not work in unreal's axis mappings